# adding fields to a redux form inside the component

Tags: redux-form

So I have a React component (called Contract) which is being fed to the reduxForm function. It's been given an array of field names (the fields property shown below) which will be part of the form.

```
export default reduxForm({
 form: 'Contract',
 fields
}, mapStateToProps)(Contract);
```

But while this component is being created, there is data (additional field names) being loaded from a server which will need to be appended to this list. That data may not load in time. Is it possible to dynamically update the list of fields and make them part of the form after this component has been created? Can it be updated inside the Contract component or is it that once this component has been created the list of fields is set in stone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using version 5 or earlier since you've got a `fields` config. You can make your fields dynamic by passing a `fields` prop to your form component instead of configuring them in `reduxForm`. ([See docs](http://redux-form.com/5.2.3/#/api/reduxForm?_k=g3suth))

I used a stateful component in this example to fetch the fields but you could also of course use a redux-connected component.

```
class ContractContainer extends Component {

  state = { fields: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetchData().then(fields => {
      this.setState({ fields });
    }
  }

  render() {
    <Contract fields={[...staticFields, ...this.state.fields]} />
  }

}
```